# ValueError: time data does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, screen-scraping, twint

I use twint for scraping data from twitter. Code as follows

```
import twint
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()



 # Configure
c = twint.Config()
c.Limit = 500
c.Since = '2022-01-01'
c.Until = '2022–02–25 23:51:31.926'
c.Search = ['Anies']
c.Store_csv = True
c.Output = "tweetsAnies.csv"

twint.run.Search(c)
```

and an error like this appears "ValueError: time data  does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"
[more details in image format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRtbZ.png)

Comment: seems fairly clear - just change your dates to be the given format!

Comment: I have changed it to the requested format, sir. 
Becomes '2022–02–25 23:51:31'. 
Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: @RaffiEl both probably need changing

Comment: @toyotaSupra, Sorry sir, maybe if I write down sorry the code will be very long, I only highlight the last line with the words "ValueError: time data does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"

Comment: @ti7 please give a clear example, Sir. That would be very helpful.

Comment: thank you all, I've retype my code, and it works

Comment: Here is link. https://pyformat.info/#datetime